# How many different functions are possible given the rules below

Tags: combinatorics

Having two sets, $A$ and $B$, being $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $B=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, how many different functions $A \to B$ are possible, given that:

$(1)$ each element of $A$ can be mapped to just one element of $B$;

$(2)$ each element of $B$ can be mapped to by at most three elements of $A$;

$(3)$ the elements $1$ and $2$ of $A$ cannot be mapped to the same element of $B$

Comment: What have you tried?  For 1) does every element of A have to be mapped, or can it be unmapped?  Can you find the number of mappings that follow only 1?

Comment: Are you looking for the number of combinations consisting of 6 ordered pairs, one from A and the other from B ?

Comment: I tried to make the question clearer. Please verify that it is still faithful to the original meaning.

Comment: @T.Gunn:  It was not clear to me that the mapping must be a function.  I asked OP to clarify whether every element of A had to be mapped.

Comment: @Ross You have a point. I put the original wording back for that part until further clarification is given.

Comment: I don't know very much about the topic. What I could come up with at first was trying the possibilities of each element of A being mapped in an element of B, but after the element 5 the possibilities depends on the mapping of the previous elements:
- 1 has 6
- 2 has 5
- 3 has 6
- 4 has 6
- 5 has 6 if none element of B are mapped by 3 elements of A or it has 5 if there are 3 elements being mapped at the same element.
- and the same for 6.
So I couldn't came up with an answer mainly due to rule (2)

Comment: @RossMillikan: yes every element of A has to be mapped.

Comment: @T.Gunn thank you very much. My English is not that good but your changes made the question clearer without changing the meaning

Answer (score 0):

Since you can a send 3 different number from A to the same number from B you can ask the question: how many 6 letters sequences can i create, from 6  options minus the bad options. The answer is 6^6. 
Lets subtract all the options where we picked 4 1's. we have (6 choose 2) times 6^2 options to create a sequence with 4 1's. 6^2 are the extra number and (6 choose 2) are all the possible positions for them.
same calculation for 4 2's, 3's...
6^6-6(6^2).
Now we have the last rule, which says 1 and 2 can't be the same.
If we send both 1 and 2 to 1, then we have 6*5*5*5 options for sequences (1 more time for 1, and 3 more options for 2-6). if we end here, we will subtract some options twice (1,1,2,2,2,2 for example). All we have to do is add these 5 options. (1,1,2,2,2,2 , 1,1,3,3,3,3 ... 1,1,6,6,6,6).
We do the same from each number from 1 to 6, 6(-6*5*5*5 +5) .
6^6-6(6^2)-6*6*5*5*5+30. Check me out, maybe i missed something.